# Write to file as administrator

Tags: c, file, administrator

I am trying to write to a file that requires administrator privileges (Windows).
How would I go about doing this? I couldn't find anything on Google, ect. 
Thank you.

Comment: You really couldn't find anything on Google? Just search for your exact title.

Answer (score 2):

Switch user ， login as administrator

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you can't login as administrator. Open the Start Menu, search for the Notepad (or whatever you're using), right click it and then "Run as administrator". Open the file through there.